# How can I use a single controller with different DBContexts?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-6.0, blazor-webassembly

I have ~70 databases which are all exactly the same structure.
What I am attempting to do is to create a quick Blazor (WASM/hosted) site on .net 6 which can access all of these sites using EF. Blazor is probably unimportant because all of the magic is happening in the 'hosted' portion which is really just a .Net API project.

So far, I have created a CommonDBContext which inherits DBContext and then individual DBContexts for each database which inherit CommonDBContext.

CommonDbContext.cs

```
 public partial class CommonDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public CommonDbContext(DbContextOptions<CommonDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        protected CommonDbContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
        {
        }
+2600 lines of EF scaffolding code
```

DB1-Context.cs

```
public partial class DB1Context : CommonDbContext
    {
        public DB1Context(DbContextOptions<DB1Context> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }
    }
```

These various context are then injected in Program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<DB1Context>(options =>
{
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DB1"));
});

builder.Services.AddDbContext<DB2Context>(options =>
{
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DB2"));
});
```

I am not convinced this is a wonderful solution for 70 databases but it is a start. This approach seems to work perfectly - I can create a controller and whichever DB context I use, it seems to pull from the proper database.

**Here's the problem**

How can I select which DBContext I want to use in the controller?  Building ~70 duplicate controllers seems very wrong but I haven't figured out how to pass in the DBContext from my request to the controller.

DopplegangerController.cs

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class DopplegangerController: ControllerBase
    {
        private DB1Context_context;  // <-- RIGHT HERE
        public DopplegangerController(DB1Contextcontext)
        {
            _context = context;
        }


        // GET: api/<DopplegangerController>
        [HttpGet]
        public List<Stuffs> Get()
        {
            return _context.Stuffs.ToList();
        }
```

Comment: DB context and connection string mechanisms can be done in the custom manner. And you can have some class like `DbContextFactory` injected to your controller. Now, the question, how do you supply which connections string to use. Where this is coming from. It can come as a claim in your JWT token. Or it can be http header. But header is not safe option. Better to allow client to specify which context to connect to during logon and add to claim

Answer (score 2):

In you `Program.cs` when configuring your services, you can give a function that will fetch the connection string depending on your settings. This function will be call each time the DbContext needs to be injected.

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<CommonDbContext>(getSQLOptions, ServiceLifetime.Transient);
void getSQLOptions(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, DbContextOptionsBuilder dbContextBuilder)
{
    YourSettings? settings = serviceProvider.GetService<YourSettings>();
    IHttpContextAccessor? httpContextAccessor = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IHttpContextAccessor>();
    
    /* Get your connectionString from your settings and HttpContext (Can be headers, query param or whatever) */
    
    dbContextBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
}
```

You can then just inject your unique CommonDbContext in your Controller and use it. You don't need the child DbContext anymore

Comment: And if I wanted to loop through all 70 databases to display a status or something on the page, this would allow me to pass 'YourSettings' through each iteration and it would just get injected as I make the call?  If that works, it is brilliant and exactly what I needed!!

Comment: For that you would bypass DI and create the 70 DbContext objects with a constructor that accepts a connection string.

Comment: Normally you sue ServiceLifetime.Scoped with DbContext instances so all the dependent services in a single HTTP request share a single instance.

Comment: @RobertWolfe My answer was assuming that you would need only 1 database per request. If you need the 70 databases in one request, indeed you will have to bypass DI.
About "YourSettings", I also assumed that it has been registered as singleton before, and you can inject it in your controller the same way as you would for any service